# VS 2012 debugging Unexpected symbol reader error while processing <file.exe>

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have a problem with debugging my program in Visual Studio 2012 - 
when I try to debug the code by inserting some breakpoints, they seem not to work - when I hover on them a message pops up

`The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unexpected symbol reader error while processing <file.exe>`

I tried searching for similar problems in the internet but I haven't found any solutions
I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Could you post the code area where you try to set this breakpoint - large enough to see why it might happen?

Comment: @gnometorule Code won't help here. It's the topology of the debuggee that needs to be detailed. It's unclear is how the [assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info) tag fits into this.

Comment: Umm, I used assembly tag because i'm writing a program in masm, but when I create a simple c program and try to debug it, the effect is the same

Comment: @Simon But how does the `assembly` tag apply to **this** question? If it doesn't, remove it.

Comment: @IInspectable okay, done

Comment: anybody? Still no solution :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[VS 2012] Ok I got the answer that fixed this problem, so I'll post this here so that people have no such problem in the future.

A solution is to change

```
   Debug -> (app) Properties-> Configuration Properties -> Debugging
```

from *Auto* to *Mixed*.
The breakpoints will automatically work.

[VS 2015] Closing all instances of VS 2015 and restarting fixes the problem for a while at least. The 2012 fix does not work.

Comment: You saved my life. Or at least saved me from hours of struggling.

Comment: Glad to help!:) greetings from gdansk

Comment: I KNEW IT! Nauka na AKO wre :D

Comment: Yep :) Odpowiedź dana przez samego AJ ;)

Comment: This worked for me, too, after I figured out where to change the property.  I edited the message to make the property path explicit.

Comment: For VS2012, this worked for me.  Using VS2015 on the same application (composed of C code and assembler code processed by MASM), the problem has come back for symbols in my assembler code.   Oddly, symbols in the C code don't have a problem.   The "fix" mentioned in this message doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I guess, you mean the setting of 'Debugger Type'

Comment: It sucks that I'm back at the same problem, having reinstalled VS2015 today (don't ask why).   It is great that this solution worked this time.

Comment: I don't have VS 2012 to verify what's in the Property Pages dialog, but in VS 2013 it's Debug -> (app) Properties-> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Debugger Type

Comment: This does absolutely nothing for VS2017!

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2017, closing all open instances and restarting worked for me.
I might have gotten away with closing fewer, for example instances with unrelated solutions open, but I have not tested that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a VS 2017 C++ DLL called from VS 2013 C# application. Upgrading the application to VS 2017 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note to the answer accepted, you should checkout `/DEBUG:FULL`  in `Linker->Debugging` in Visual Studio 2017 upwards

> Beginning in Visual Studio 2017, the build system in the IDE defaults to /DEBUG:FASTLINK.

> This limited PDB can't be used for debugging when the required build products are not available, such as when the executable is deployed on another computer.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

In VS2017, I have to clean up and close the whole solution, then delete the .vs folder from the solution folder, then recompile to fix it.