# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unexpected symbol reader error while processing <file> (Server-side symbols)

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

Sometimes while debugging in Visual Studio 2013, I get hollow breakpoints and this message for them:

The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unexpected symbol reader error while processing App_Web_i5dbbmvv.dll (Server-side symbols).

When this happens, the breakpoints will not be hit (obviously). Additionally, if I get an exception while running in this state, I'll get the message "The source file is different from when the module was built. Would you like the debugger to use it anyway?"

Building again does not fix this. Sometimes a clean-and-rebuild will do the trick, other times I have to clean -> exit VS -> reopen VS -> build.

This is the same error as this post [VS 2012 debugging Unexpected symbol reader error while processing <file.exe>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020886/vs-2012-debugging-unexpected-symbol-reader-error-while-processing-file-exe)

**but the posted solution is for C++, and that option appears to not exist when developing C#.**

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: yes, it is an MVC application + a WCF service.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ASP.NET then try [deleting your generated temp files](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CleanUpYourTempFiles.aspx).

> clean up %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ **VERSION** \Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: I will try this the next time it happens and report back.

Comment: That might have done the trick. I couldn't find the specific file that was referenced by the breakpoint's message, but all the files in there were definitely in the same format: App_<filename>_<gibberish string>.dll. I wonder if this is just a temporary fix though.

Comment: It was temporary. The breakpoint errors are back. Additionally, to delete the temp files, I have to quit VS2013 so I can get past the "can't delete in-use files" message. But it turns out that just restarting VS will clear the issue. No need to even delete those files. I'm unaccepting this answer, since it isn't a long-term solution and wasn't the real short-term solution either.

Comment: I've got the same problem.  Only started happening in the last couple of days - either after I installed Update2, or after I switched my app to use IIS instead of IISExpress.

Comment: I've started getting it too - also recently installed Update 3 (bypassed Update 2) but it was working without a problem with IIS prior to that. Very frustrating.

Comment: Four years later, seeing this in VS2015. Just started happening out of the blue -- I haven't patched VS recently or anything like that. But killing *all* instances of VS and restarting fixed the problem.